# Bounding boxes controlling movement incorrectly

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am recreating pong in tkinter and I have ran into 2 issues. Both of them are due to my hitboxes.

Here is my code...

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

## -- Setup -- ##
# Window
window = Tk()
window.title("Pong!")

# Movement
up1 = False
down1 = False
up2 = False
down2 = False

# Images
Ball = PhotoImage(file = "ball.png")
Player = PhotoImage(file = "R.png")

# Canvas
Game = Canvas(window, width = 700, height = 500) # Game window
Game.config(bg = "black")
Game.config(scrollregion = Game.bbox(ALL))
Game.pack()

P1 = Game.create_image(20, 250, image = Player) # Player One
Ba = Game.create_image(350, 250, image = Ball) # Ball
P2 = Game.create_image(680, 250, image = Player) # Player Two
Top = Game.create_line(1, 3, 700, 3, fill = "red") # Top Hitbox
Dwn = Game.create_line(1, 499, 700, 499, fill = "red") # Bottom Hitbox
Right = Game.create_line(699, 1, 699, 500, fill = "red") # Left Hitbox
Left = Game.create_line(2, 1, 2, 500, fill = "red") # Right Hitbox

BaX = 0.5 # Random int for the speed of the ball
BaY = 0 # Random int for the Y axis of the ball
Turn = "P1" # Last hit of the ball (used to help with hit detection)

P1Score = 0 # Player 1 Score
P2Score = 0 # Player 2 Score

## -- Def -- ##
def KeyDown(event): # Controller for Key presses
    global up1, down1, up2, down2, Turn
    if event.char == "w" or event.char == "W":
        up1 = True
    elif event.char == "s" or event.char == "S":
        down1 = True
    if event.char == "i" or event.char == "I":
        up2 = True
    elif event.char == "k" or event.char == "K":
        down2 = True

def KeyUp(event): # Controller for Key releases
    global up1, down1, up2, down2
    if event.char == "w" or event.char == "W":
        up1 = False
    elif event.char == "s" or event.char == "S":
        down1 = False
    if event.char == "i" or event.char == "I":
        up2 = False
    elif event.char == "k" or event.char == "K":
        down2 = False

def Check(): # Controller for movment and hit detection
    ## -- Movement Detection -- ##
    global up1, down1, up2, down2, P1, P2, Ba, BaY, BaX, Turn, P1Score, P2Score
    if up1 == True:
        Game.move(P1, 0, -1)
    elif down1 == True:
        Game.move(P1, 0, 1)

    if up2 == True:
        Game.move(P2, 0, -1)
    elif down2 == True:
        Game.move(P2, 0, 1)

    ## -- Ball Movement -- ##
    # Ball
    if BaY == -2: # BaY controlls angle
        BaY = 0.2
    elif BaY == -1:
        BaY = -0.1
    elif BaY == 0:
        BaY = -0.05
    elif BaY == 1:
        BaY = 0.1
    elif BaY == 2:
        BaY = 0.2

    Game.move(Ba, BaX, BaY)

    ## -- Hit Reg -- ##
    # Hitboxes
    BaBbox = Game.bbox(Ba) # Hitboxes
    TopBbox = Game.bbox(Top)
    DwnBbox = Game.bbox(Dwn)
    LBbox = Game.bbox(Left)
    RBbox = Game.bbox(Right)
    # Ball Bounce (P1/P2)
    if P1 in Game.find_overlapping(*BaBbox):
        BaX = 0.5
    if P2 in Game.find_overlapping(*BaBbox):
        BaX = -0.5
    # Ball Bounce (Top/Dwn)
    if Ba in Game.find_overlapping(*TopBbox):
        BaY = BaY - BaY - BaY
    if Ba in Game.find_overlapping(*DwnBbox):
        BaY = BaY + BaY + BaY
    # Scoring
    if Ba in Game.find_overlapping(*LBbox):
        P2Score = P2Score + 1
        Start()
    if Ba in Game.find_overlapping(*RBbox):
        P1Score = P1Score + 1
        Start()

    window.after(2, Check) # Calls itself

def Start(): # Used to Start and Restart the game
    global BaY
    BaY = random.randint(-2,2)

## -- Main -- ##
window.bind("<Key>", KeyDown)
window.bind("<KeyRelease>", KeyUp)
Start()
Check()
window.mainloop()
```

My first issue is the top and bottom border, sometimes the ball will just be sucked into the void and I can't locate where the issue is.
My second issue is the left and right borders, they aren't resetting.

I am still trying to learn how to use canvas for this sort of thing so I am sorry for any sloppy code or the resolutions to my issues being obvious.

Comment: ***"issue is the top and bottom border"***: For the *bottom*, replace `BaY = BaY + BaY + BaY` with `BaY = -0.5` to reverse the direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "left and right borders, they aren't resetting"?

Comment: No for some reason they are not resetting for me